# Postgres : Unable to pass the list of ids in IN clause in JDBC

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using postgres DB. I want to pass the list of ids in IN clause. The type of column is int8. I have list of Long in the code.

This is the code

I am getting below exception :
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

I tried using converting to String array and using varchar. But none of that works.
Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: String sql = "select id, name from table where id in (?::int8[])";
Array sqlArray = con.createArrayOf("bigint", ids.toArray(new Long[ids.size()]));
ps.setArray(1, sqlArray);

Comment: This is a tough one to handle in Java.  Perhaps the best you can do is to have a fixed number of parameters, e.g. for three use `WHERE col IN (?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: The list is being passed from upstream and I can't update the sql easily as it is tightly coupled with another module.

Comment: Change your query to `select id, name from table where id = any (?)`. Everything else seems fine.